# Display inline log in flipper into multiple line

Tags: react-native, fbflipper

I'm using react native and the new flipper debugger. I have a very simple question, currently when i log a big object it only display in one line like this :

[image]

Is there a way to display it in a better way like in chrome debugger tools like this :
[image]

As it would be easier to navigate inside a log of an object with chrome like display instead of scrolling horizontally through one line.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

Flipper developers [have plans to add multiline support](https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/1010).

Until then you can try formatting your logs using this pattern:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(object, null, 2))
```